# Joint distribution of sample correlations of variables taken from a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: correlation, independence, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let us assume [multivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) vector $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ with mean vector $\mu$ and variance-covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

A sample correlation will not exactly equal its population parameter, but should limit to the correct value. There exists a sampling distribution for a sample correlation $r$ at sample size $n$ as follows

$$f(r) = \frac{(n-2)\Gamma(n-1)(1-\rho^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(1-r^2)^{\frac{n-4}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \Gamma \left( n - \frac{1}{2} \right) (1 - \rho r)^{n - \frac{3}{2}}} {_2}F_1 \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{2} (2n-1); \frac{1}{2} (\rho r +1) \right)$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and ${_2}F_1$ is the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

In the limit as the sample size increases we should expect sample correlations to become independent as they approach (possibly distinct) constants. For two independent sample correlations $r_{i,j}$ and $r_{k,l}$ we can just assume that

$f(r_{i,j}, r_{k,l}) = f(r_{i,j})f({r_{k,l}})$

from the definition of independence. But perhaps sample correlations are not independent. We know that for three variables there are three possible correlations, and that [Langford *et al* 2001](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4745702_Is_the_Property_of_Being_Positively_Correlated_Transitive) showed that they are not logically independent.

For a collection of sample correlations $r_1, \cdots, r_q$ for all pairs of variables from a multivariate Gaussian distribution, what is their joint distribution $f(r_1, \cdots, r_q)$?